# How can I keep a div's width relative to a resizable div with jQuery and jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I keep a div's width relative to a resizable div with jQuery and jQuery UI. I have the following code:

```
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
<div id="auto-resize">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resize auto</h3>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#resizable").resizable();
    });
</script>
```

How can I keep the 'auto-resize' div the same as the 'resizable' div while it resizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event `resize` from `resizable` and set the size of the other div inside there:

```
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
<div id="auto-resize">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resize auto</h3>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#resizable").resizable({
            resize: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#auto-resize").width(ui.size.width);
                $("#auto-resize").height(ui.size.height);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/m4dQ8/

Answer (score 0):

There's a `resize` event generated, so you just have to do this :

```
$("#resizable").resizable().on('resize', function(){
  $('#auto-resize').width($(this).width());
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/axizida/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `resize` event can be used here. [JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jaypeagi/TXGgL/1/).

```
$(function() {
    $("#resizable").resizable()
    .resize(function() {
        $("#auto-resize")
            .height($(this).height())
            .width($(this).width());
    });
});
```